# How to add a transverse force to a point on a simple wave equation?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, waves, string, stress-strain

### Background

Imagine simple wave equation, say of a string fixed at both ends, in this form:

$$ρ y_{tt} = \frac{T}{A}y_{xx}$$

Or with an added velocity damping term like:

$$ρ y_{tt} = \frac{T}{A}y_{xx} - B y_t$$

$ρ$ is density, $T$ is tension, $A$ is cross sectional area. Subscripts of $x$ and $t$ are derivatives of position along length and time.

This is being solved by substituting finite differences sample by sample say with 50-100 nodes.

### Question

How can you add an external transverse force of a given Newtons (like a finger or object pressing on the "string") to only one point (finite difference node) along the length? ie. so the equation at that point becomes:

$$ρ y_{tt} = \frac{T}{A}y_{xx} - B y_t + [\frac{F}{?}]$$

Each term in the basic equation is in units of $\frac{N}{m^3}$ or $\frac{kg*s}{m^2}$ so something needs to happen to put the force against $\frac{1}{m^3}$.

But I am not sure how to do this. I tried dividing it by $A*Δx$ for the given point I was applying it to but this seemed wrong as this term was so tiny it magnified the F to a massive number and I didn't get a good output.

So perhaps I need to involve something like $F_x$ or $F_{xx}$ with this? So that the force is spread to the two points on either side as well? I don't know intuitively or mathematically how it should work.

### Example

A simple example would be a metal string like a guitar string where tension $T \approx 70$, density $ρ \approx 8000$, cross sectional area $A \approx 1E-6$, and length $L \approx 0.65$, say with 50-100 nodes. In this case, consistently applying a force of $5 N$ or so at any single point should displace that point at equilibrium around ~1 cm (just by playing with a guitar casually).

But I can't figure out how to add the $5 N$ force in any way to a single point that gives this approximate result.

Any solution or explanation for how to do this? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the way to do it is to work with the differential equation, rather than a finite difference approximation.  The thing that happens with a point loading like this is the slope changes discontinuously at the point of loading:  $$(y_x^+-y_x^-)T=F$$This change in slope occurs at the point that the force F is applied.  If you have a nodal point that the location of force application, then only the finite difference equation at the point of application is affected.

Comment: Thank you Chet! I actually realize my formula was correct and I just had an error in my code after coming back to it today. But your explanation was very helpful in any case, as it helped me better understand how it works and the wave equation. It also provides an interesting alternative approach to adding the force - by direct addition/subtraction from $y_{xx}$ at that point. Thanks again.